# Find a variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of javascript variables on my page:

```
var opts_???? = ...
var opts_???? = ...
var opts_???? = ...
```

The `????` is assigned a random number by the content management system, so I don't know the full name of the variable.

I'm looking for any undefined ones.

Is there a way in jQuery to loop through all variables that start with `opts_` so that I can test them for being undefined?

The variables are all global, if that helps.

If not in jQuery, I'll settle for regular javascript.

Comment: Does the variable name correspond to a name, class, or id attribute of an html element on the page?

Comment: No these are just variables

Comment: what do you mean by *undefined*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is only possible if the variables have all been declared at global scope (and therefore also available as properties of the global `window` object).

Since yours are, you can use `Object.keys(window)` to obtain the names of all such properties, and then use either `$.each` or `Array.prototype.forEach` to test each of them in turn.

```
var opts = Object.keys(window).filter(function(n) {
    return n.substring(0, 5) === 'opts_';
});

var opts_undefined = opts.filter(function(n) {
    return window[n] === undefined;
});
```

[written as two calls for clarity over efficiency]

Answer (score 6):

If the variables are in the global scope (that is, not created within a function) they should also be available as properties on the `window` object. In other words, the variable `opts_1234` can also be accessed as `window.opts_1234` or `window['opts_1234']`.

The easiest way to grab all the variables would be:

```
var variables = Object.keys(window).filter(function(prop) {
    return prop.substring(0, 5) === 'opts_';
});
```

Now `variables` contains an array of names, like `['opts_1', 'opts_666']`

You can also extend that filter to only include those variables that aren't undefined:

```
var variables = Object.keys(window).filter(function(prop) {
    return prop.substring(0, 5) === 'opts_' && window[prop] !== undefined;
});
```

Comment: `.indexOf` is (IMHO) the wrong function for this job.

Comment: I considered using a regex, but I'm not sure it would make a big difference. What do you suggest?

Comment: well, in my answer I've used `.substring()`, since I explicitly only want to test the first five characters.    The problem with `.indexOf` is that it'll scan the entire string unnecessarily.

Comment: Good point, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

```js
var opts_1 = 'test';
var opts_2 = 'test1';
var opts_3 = 'test2';
var opts_4 = undefined;

var vars = Object.keys(window).filter(function(key){
   return (key.indexOf("opts_")!=-1 && window[key] == undefined) 
});
console.log(vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var marker='opts_';
var results=$('selector').find(marker);
```

Hope This will help you